# Copying elements of first array to second one without dual com

Tags: javascript

I've got some problems with these two arrays.

```
for (i = 0; i < post_data_route.length; i++) {
    route_array.push(coordinates_array[post_data_route[i] - 1]);
}
route_array[route_array.length - 1][0] -= 0.00001;
route_array[route_array.length - 1][1] -= 0.00001;
```

`route_array[route_array.length - 1]` equals `route_array[0]` but when I try to change one of them second one changes too. I guess that's about the pointer but why does it happen? Isn't it just pushing values of array to another one? 
How could I get rid of it? 
Thanks for your answers and suggestions.

Comment: since `post_data_route` contains other arrays, then you're just adding the same references to `route_array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the data, that means, you get a copy.

> The **`slice()`** method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

```
for (i = 0; i < post_data_route.length; i++) {
    route_array.push(coordinates_array[post_data_route[i] - 1].slice());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since my array isn't full filled with arrays this is not exactly what I was looking for but I'm a bit closer now. I think this is the answer there. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: slice will also copy the object references(of array's elements) as is and will have the same effect.

Comment: @brawl_up, we actually don't know, how your data look like, to give a valid answer, please add this part to your question.

Comment: @SachinG. you are right sir. Did it with `Array.prototype.slice.call`. Now this one is completely wrecked. Thank you for your attention guys.

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing not the values, but another array, because your array is multidimensional. You need to push the value of each dimensions separately.

Example:

```
route_array.push([
      coordinates_array[post_data_route[i] - 1][0],
      coordinates_array[post_data_route[i] - 1][1]
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create new objects and arrays with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourArray))`

its not so nice but its working